# Unable to open Clearcase raima database.

Tags: java, clearcase, raima

I am trying to read raima database of Clearcase. The db directory is copied from the vob storage and renamd to vob_db. The location where the vob_db is present, there exists the VOB_DB.java file and dependent dlls and jar file. In fact they were copied from below zip file that contains sample program

[http://raima.com/wp-content/uploads/helloWorldSamples/HelloWorld_JDBC_win64.zip][1]

Below java code ( VOB_DB.java ) is written just to open an close database.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class VOB_DB {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:raima:rdm://local");
    Statement Stmt = Conn.createStatement ();
    Stmt.execute ("OPEN DATABASE vob_db");
    Stmt.close ();
    Conn.close ();        
    }
}
```

The above code compiles successfully. But when I run it throws below message.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class JAVA_DB
```

I am really not sure what wrong is with the program or is there anything missing in it or any dependancy is not set.

Comment: Trying to access the tables stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to tell you what to do but directly accessing a ClearCase Raima database is asking for serious trouble.  Not something you want to do if your company's intellectual property is stored there.

There are APIs and command line options available for almost anything you would want to do with ClearCase.

Also, the Raima database used for ClearCase is not 100% off-the-shelf.  There are a number of additional features which are not documented.